# Div ignores margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been looking for a solution to this for quite a while now and I just can't seem to get it right.

http://www.bootply.com/f3A3PJzfxa#

I want a slight margin under the form heading but the margins I apply are just ignored. I tried setting display:block on the div as suggested by some other post on SO but that didn't work either. Also applying clearfixes didn't solve it.

Anybody has any suggestions? Thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

You missed the px

```
try this 
.form-heading {
    margin-bottom: 5000px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe that I failed to see that for over an hour. I should have taken a step back and looked at it more clearly. :D